# What exactly is Nada, Bindu and Kala?

Tags: tantra, shaivism, meditation, shaktism, kashmiri-shaivism

I have come across the term Nada, Bindu and Kala etc many times and they seem to be talking about various different concepts sometimes personal and sometimes cosmic.

In one explanation Bindu is something in the beginning of the creation and Nada is also created during creation.

But in another explanation Bindu is the blue dot which appears while mediating and Nada is the sound heard during meditation either Omkara or String instruments and Flutes.

So is there a cosmic meaning and then personal meaning? Please explain both the concepts clearly so that even an Average Joe can understand.

Comment: Hint. 'Nada' vibrates ( Nadham is sound )...Nadhaswaram - instrument that produces sound. The primordial waveform was sound emanated from ...? Bindu is 'dot' in forehead -> at the location of Ajna chakra between eye brows. As you raise up in Kundalini you will come to a 'point' ( refer to Vinayagar Agaval translations to English -> it's called Karum Pulli ( black dot) :-)) ...Now what is Black & is a dot( with enough density ...Wink, Wink) . The personal meaning will follow as you raise your snakes up:- )... Kala is NOT time. it is Art. Kalai(Tamil) means art.i.e. you have to learn it! what?

Answer (score 2):

Nada is the sound of Om, Bindu is a point at which one can fix their awareness in the head. Kala means time (as kāla) or creation, energy (as kalā). As you said, there is often a cosmic and personal meaning to the terms used.

**Nada**

*Haṭhapradīpikā*:

> **3.100. In the body, the Nada becomes bindu itself.**
>
> **4.1. Salutations to Shiva, the Guru, who is of the form of Nada, bindu and experience; the person ever devoted to these obtains the stainless state.**
>
> **4.102. Whatever is heard of the nature of the mystical Nada is indeed Shakti. That in which all the elements find dissolution, the formless, that is the supreme Lord (Parameshvara). Thus ends the inquiry into Nada.**

So, the *Haṭhapradīpikā* not only tells us what Nada is, but that it is closely-related to bindu. It suggests, by focusing on the bindu, one hears Nada. Placing attention at the bindu, one experiences the shakti of Shiva, which one hears as Nada or Shabda Brahman. Other synonyms of Nada are Om, pranava, and vac/vak, who is deified as the goddess Vac/k. In short, Nada is the sound of experience at its very core, in deep meditation and stillness. The mind is said to dissolve into this sound, known as *laya*, where all duality falls away.

**Bindu**

*Gorakṣaśataka*:

> **72. Bindu is Shiva, rajas is Shakti; bindu is the moon, rajas the sun; from the mingling of these two, truly, one obtains the highest state.**

Like the *Haṭhapradīpikā*, it also equates bindu with Shiva. Bindu and Shiva are masculine and inactive or still, whereas rajas and Shakti are feminine and active. The moon is associated with the Ida nadi and the Sun with Pingala. The merging of these two is to reside in Sushumna, where one obtains the highest state. On this, the *Haṭhapradīpikā* says,

> **4.17. The Sun and the Moon create [the division of] Time in the form of day and night. Sushumna consumes Time. This is a secret.**

This means, one experiences timelessness or eternity in Sushumna. The place at which the Ida, Pingala and Sushumna merge is between the eyebrows, which is described, in the same text, as the seat of Shiva.

> **4.48. Between the eyebrows is the seat of Shiva, wherein the mind is quiescent. This state is known as the Turiya [fourth state of consciousness, beyond the states of waking, dreaming, and dreamless sleep]. There, Time (Death) is not.**

It is connected with time because exhalation is associated with night (in Ida, the moon) and inhalation (in Pingala, the sun) with day. The cessation of inhalation and exhalation happens in Sushumna and is described as consuming time (*kāla*). When the mind is not still, bindu travels down (on exhalation) and rajas travels up (on inhlation). The cessation of their fluctuation is yoga, and occurs between the eyebrows - where Shiva merges with Shakti.

**Kala**

From these verses, we get an idea of Kala, time, meaning death.

Bindu as both the beginning of the creation and a blue dot which appears when meditating are not in conflict with each other, nor are Nada as both created during creation and the sound heard during meditation.

If one sees the blue dot, they are merged in the primordial energy, without form. This is what is meant by beginning of the creation. Creation implies form and manifestation. Before creation, there was formlessness.

With the stirring of creation, there was vibration and this is Nada. Abiding in the same place as bindu, one hears this primordial vibration. To experience both bindu and Nada is to suspend time, Kala. Time implies motion and what changes. Bindu and Nada refer to experiencing the unchangeable, that which is beyond time.